# How to find functional interface candidates in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, structural-search

I'm trying to use search structurally to find interfaces that could be annotated with `@FunctionalInterface` since they only contain a single abstract method but aren't annotated yet.

My current structural search template looks like this:

```java
@$TheAnnotation$
interface $Interface$ { 
  $ReturnType$ $Method$ ($ParameterType$ $Parameter$);
}
```

I've added the following filters

- Parameters: count -> `[0, ∞]`
- TheAnnotation: script -> `TheAnnotation.getClass() != FunctionalInterface.class`

but that does not seem to work as the result will contain classes annotated with @FunctionalInterface nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has a "Interface may be annotated @FunctionalInterface" inspection, you may want to use instead. It has a quick fix to add the `@FunctionalInteface` annotation.

But if you insist on using Structural Search, here's a template that should work:

```
<searchConfiguration name="Unnamed" text="@$TheAnnotation$&#10;interface $Interface$ {&#10;  abstract $ReturnType$ $Method$ ($ParameterType$ $Parameter$);&#10;  abstract $ReturnType2$ $Method2$ ($ParameterType2$ $Parameter2$);&#10;}" recursive="false" caseInsensitive="false" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="TheAnnotation" regexp="FunctionalInterface" minCount="0" maxCount="0" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Method" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Interface" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="ReturnType" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="ReturnType2" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="ParameterType" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="ParameterType2" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Parameter" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Parameter2" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Method2" minCount="0" maxCount="0" within="" contains="" />
</searchConfiguration>
```

(copy the xml and using the "Import Template from Clipboard" action under the tool button in the Structural Search dialog)

Comment: Thanks for the hints on both accounts. I will use the existing inspection but the structural search example is also valuable as it is a powerful device that I haven't learned to use to its full potential yet. I had to remove the `abstract` keywords in the resulting structural search template for it to work.